# Difference in keep and kept

Tags: grammar, active-vs-passive

I am an English learner and i am confused in a sentence. The sentence

> *The bricks are **keep** in a kiln.*

This sentence is about a process. This sentence seems absurd to me. So i wrote

> *The bricks are **kept** in a kiln.*

I want to know if it is a present tense. Why past participle form looks more accurate in this sentence.

If this sentence is in passive what will be its active voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called "past participle" is used in other ways without any sense of "past".

In particular, it is the normal way to form a passive, and the tense of the passive is that of the auxiliary.

So, "are kept" is present passive.

"Are keep" is not grammatical: in a verb phrase, parts of "be" must be followed by a participle: either the "past participle" for a passive ("are kept") or the "present participle" for a continuous form ("are keeping").

The active sentence corresponding to your example would be "They keep the bricks in a kiln" or "Somebody keeps the bricks in a kiln", or "Mr Johnson keeps the bricks in a kiln" etc. Do you see why the passive is useful?

Comment: ...Thanks sir. But sir which are the subject and object in my sentence. Its quite confusing in this sentence. I am very clear with the usage of verb phrase.

Comment: "The bricks" is the subject. A passive sentence has no object.